Definitions of different types of symmetries
I'm a math student and I started studying physics last year. I'm sorry if this question has been asked before but I'm completely confused about it. In page 30 of the book "String theory and M-theory" by Becker, Becker and Schwarz, the authors say that the string sigma-model action for the bosonic string in Minkowski space-time has a number of symmetries: Poincare transformations, reparametrizations and Weil transformations. I really have trouble with understanding these symmetries and their differences and I am also confused about some other terms like internal symmetry, local symmetry and global symmetry and also diffeomorphism invariance, coordinate transformation and gause invariance (or gauge transformation). I would really appreciate if someone explain these definitions in a very simply way.

Suggestion to the post (v3): 1. Consider to only ask 1 question. 2. Consider to explicitly mention troubling/confusing points.

Do you know about Lie groups, or group theory in general?

@Qmechanic Sure. Thank you for the comment.

@MitchellPorter Yes, I'm very good at both.
